# Java Web Start / JNLP for non-GUI console application / Code update distribution

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a simple data validation command line utility that I've written in Java.  We distribute this utility to our clients as a JAR file.  Our clients run this utility on data in their local machines.

Since we frequently update this validation tool, it would be nice to be able to distribute this using Java Web Start / JNLP so that they receive code updates automatically.

From what I can gather, Java web start is most commonly used for Swing/UI based apps. Can it be used for command line console applications?  Or if there is another way to tackle this issue, let me know.

Comment: I think most JNLP programs are still basically "sandboxed" in such a way that if the user wants to open/save a file they have to select/confirm it through a "trusted" interface, a bit like [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). So if your program accesses lots of files, you probably have to sign your app. (And if self-signed, convince the user to click through scary dialogs to give it unfettered access.)

Comment: For us, that might be a deal killer for using JNLP.  Our app accesses a ton of files. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, you could sign it to avoid the sandboxing, but I would wager the actual command-line invocation via JNLP is going to be a lot uglier than, say, `myapp -in infile.txt -out outfile.txt`. Some sort of home-grown "New update is available!" scheme might be easier.

Answer (score -1):

Java Web Start does assume a GUI app and does its best to hide the code it downloads from the users.  It doesn't seem right for a command line app that users are apt to, for example, incorporate in their own scripts.

Maybe you could write a simple GUI that retrieves the latest version of your command-line JAR and puts it where your users are expecting it, and put that GUI in JWS.